# IntelliJ not showing some Git commits

Tags: git, intellij-idea

We moved almost all our source files into different folders in a single Git commit on October 19. It's just one of those things... overdue to happen... and we did it.

When I use Git to show the history of **any** file, it works fine, it spits out the entire history.

```
git log <file name>
```

If, however, I select any file in IntelliJ and "`Show history`", the results are not as desired:

- For some files the history shows fine
- For some files no history is shown from before the October 19 commit that moved the file. No error is shown, it just shows no entries (commits) in the "`Show history`" list

This happens consistently for certain files; not all of them, but a considerable amount.

Why does IntelliJ do this and how can it stop it! I want to see all my history.

Thank you.

Comment: So what do you mean specifically by "no history is shown"?  Do you not get anything back from IntelliJ for that file at all?  Do you see an error?  Do you get some feedback from the actual command that IntelliJ is running against Git (looks something like `git -c core.quotepath=false log --name-status --pretty=format:%x01%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%P%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x02%at%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 HEAD --max-count=1000 -- your-file`) ?

Comment: I've clarified a bit: *No error is shown, it just shows no entries (commits) in the "`Show history`" list*. I don't think the command that you show is really what IntelliJ uses, how did you get to that? For me it stops at the October 19 commit for **all** files, not just for *some files*, as I described in the question. The command can be easily fixed by adding a `--follow`, but how would I tell IntelliJ that? This is IntelliJ 13.1.5 (and I will upgrade it now).